# Matching user inputs with tripplestore data

Tags: sparql

I am trying to develop a decision support system for soybean disease analysis using protege, fuseki server and php. I want to take input from a user and a return a disease name based on the matching of the literal. The query I am trying is :

```
$sparql = "PREFIX : <http://localhost/soy_test1#>
         select ?Diaporthe_stem_canker where {?Diaporthe_stem_canker :hasTOC ' . TOC . ' . ' . TOC .' :hasTOC 'July'}";
```

It always returns Diaporthe_stem_canker no matter what the input is. I am trying to find what's the error in the sparql query. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

**Edit**

The ontology I have is as follows:

A plant soybean is described by some plant descriptors. Plant descriptor has several types with some attribute values.

Example:

```
:PlantDescriptor :hasType "EnvironmentalDescriptors" .
:PlantDescriptor :hasAttribute :TOC .
:PlantDescriptor :hasTOC "July" .
:TOC rdfs:subClassOf :Attribute .
```

where PlantDescriptor and Attribute are the concepts of the ontology.

I am trying to take an input from the user for the attribute "TOC", which I want to match whether it's "July" or not; if it matches with July then it will return the disease name Diaporthe-stem-canker.

The string part is for matching the user input text with the value "July". That's why I have used it as a php variable inside SPARQL Query.

The query that I used in my Query engine is like this:

```
PREFIX : <http://localhost/soy_test1#>
select distinct ?P ?X ?Time 
where {?PlantDescriptor :hasType ?P . 
       ?PlantDescriptor :hasAttribute ?X. 
       ?X :hasTOC "July" . 
       ?X :hasTOC ?Time .}
```

which returns the value "July" under ?Time, the url for Attribute concept and the type of the PlantDescriptor for the corresponding Attribute.

Hope I have made my point more clear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Please show the real SPARQL query here, it's not readable in its current form which is specific to a programming language with some String operations that I'm not used to. 2. Provide sample data 3. Provide what you would expect and what you currently get back from the query.

Comment: thanks for your response, i have posted an edit, any help would be appreciated. sorry i forgot to mention the output i am getting at present...it shows the diease name for any thing i provide as input.

Comment: From your initial example, you're setting the value of TOC which is a PHP variable that comes from some user input, right? If that's true, the second triple pattern starts with the same literal, which is the object of the first literal. Literals in subject position are not allowed in RDF triples.

Comment: @AKSW...okay...so is there any other way I can check the matching ?

Comment: What is the user input? The value of `:hasToc`? I mean do you understand what happens if you set the PHP variable? Result is a query like `select ?Diaporthe_stem_canker where {?Diaporthe_stem_canker :hasTOC "user_val" . "user_val" :hasTOC 'July'}` I don't think this is what you want

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I am doing, but the problem is...it is showing Diaporthe_stem_canker for any value-for July and also for anything I give as input....that is the problem,the check for matching is not working. I have tried string matching using filter, but same thing happens.

Comment: No, what I mean is that a literal "user_val" can't be a subject in RDF. And I don't understand what you mean by "it is showing Diaporthe_stem_canker". `?Diaporthe_stem_canker` is a variable in your SPARQL query

Answer (score 0):

The example isn't entirely clear because you say you are searching for `Diaporthe-stem-canker`, but that's not in your sample data. Assuming `Diaporthe-stem-canker` is a `PlantDescriptor`, the following query could get you what you need:

```
SELECT ?disease
WHERE { 
   ?disease :hasTOC "July" .
}
```

And in your case the "July" string is inserted into the string, so you  may have something like the following if you were using PHP (no idea what your syntax is(:

```
$sparql = "PREFIX : <http://localhost/soy_test1#>
     select ?disease where {?disease :hasTOC " . $date . " . }"
```

...where `$date` is bound to "July", etc.

Comment: In SPARQL, you don't always need to have a fact in the sample data...please check this tutorial http://www.semantic-web-journal.net/system/files/swj1004.pdf . My ontology is kind of similar to this example.

Comment: uh, I'm just talking about having a good data set to help respond to your question.

Comment: Okay I myself am now clear about what I am actually looking for...how can I include a $_POST['some_variable'] inside a SPARQL code block ? I want to check a value that has been submitted through a form in php using SPARQL.

Comment: @user1790 From your initial example, you're setting the value of TOC which is a PHP variable that comes from some user input, right? If that's true, the second triple pattern starts with the same literal, which is the object of the first literal. Literals in subject position are not allowed in RDF triples.